# How to get json response back into rails app json.parse unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to interact with an api with my rails application

http://api.placemeter.net/api/shake/line/?start=-120&end=0

This returns back a response like this

```
{"average_line_wait_secs": [0, 0, 0], "end": 1396624139, "timestamps": [1396623960, 1396624020, 1396624080], "average_line_length": [0, 0, 0], "start": 1396623960}
```

I want to grab this json data to play with in my rails application.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @shakeline = JSON.parse('http://api.placemeter.net/api/shake/line/?start=-120&end=0')
  end 

end
```

I think JSON.parse is supposed to help me with this.

Here is my error

```
757: unexpected token at 'http://api.placemeter.net/api/shake/line/?start=-120&end=0'
```

eventually I want the json response be a ruby data structure which I will build something with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as below

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    require 'open-uri'
    JSON.parse(open('http://api.placemeter.net/api/shake/line/?start=-120&end=0').read))
  end 
end
```

Check this [`OpenURI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html#module-OpenURI-label-Example) documentation.

Comment: is it returning the response in an array?

Comment: @Jngai1297 No.. `Hash`.. I can see, from the URL...you mentioned. But you can check the same using method `#class`.